# SSRS Printing causes calculated field to double

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services

I have an SSRS report in which I have some custom code to do some complex conditional calculations.  Everything seems to work fine; however, when I go to print my report, the field in which I have the custom code doubles for some reason.  I can't figure out why this is happening.  When exporting the file to excel, the amount shows up correctly.  The amount also shows on the screen correctly.  It only changes when sending the report to the printer.

Has anyone else seen this issue?

Below is a sample of the call to my custom code:

```
Code.SumLARSOE(Parameters!pThousandsToggle.Value,
               "PeriodActual",
               Fields!OutlineSequence.Value,
               Sum(Fields!Actual.Value))
```

Below is a sample of the calculations being performed in that call:
In my custom code I have LARPA and SOEPA defined as doubles

```
Public Function SumLARSOE (ByVal toggle As String, _
                                 runType As String, _
                                 sequence As Integer, _
                                 amount As Double) As Double
Select Case runType
    Case "PeriodActual"
        Select Case sequence
            Case NNN To NNN
                If toggle = True
                    LARPA = (LARPA + (amount / 1000))
                    SOEPA = (SOEPA + (amount / 1000))
                    amount = (amount / 1000)
                Else
                    LARPA = (LARPA + amount)
                    SOEPA = (SOEPA + amount)
                End If

            Case NNN
                amount = LARPA

            Case NNN To NNN
                If toggle = True
                    SOEPA = (SOEPA + (amount / 1000))
                    amount = (amount / 1000)
                Else
                    SOEPA = (SOEPA + amount)
                End If

            Case NNN
                amount = SOEPA

            Case Else
                If toggle = True
                    amount = (amount / 1000)
                End If

        End Select

... Additional logic here for other cases, but logic follows above example

    Return amount
End Function
```

Below is the information on my current environment.

Microsoft Visual Studio 2010
Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.01590 SP1Rel

Installed Version: IDE Standard

Microsoft Visual Basic 2010   01011-532-2002361-70584
Microsoft Visual Basic 2010

Microsoft Visual C# 2010   01011-532-2002361-70584
Microsoft Visual C# 2010

Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications 3.0   01011-532-2002361-70584
Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications 3.0

Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010   01011-532-2002361-70584
Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010

SQL Server Analysis Services
Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Services Designer 
Version 11.0.6020.0

SQL Server Integration Services
Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Designer
Version 11.0.6020.0

SQL Server Reporting Services
Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Designers 
Version 11.0.6020.0

Visual Studio 2010 Shell (Integrated) - ENU Service Pack 1 (KB983509)   KB983509
This service pack is for Visual Studio 2010 Shell (Integrated) - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this service pack will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/983509.

SQL Prompt 8
For more information about SQL Prompt, see the Red Gate website at
http://www.red-gate.com
For customer support, call 1-866-733-4283.
Copyright © 2006–2009 Red Gate Software Ltd

Comment: In your custom code, what does the function return? It doesn't look complete.

Comment: Yeah, I just posted a little snippet of the custom code, it returns the value of amount, unless the sequence values are 2 specific values which then returns one of the sums that I show in the custom code snippet (SOEPA and LARPA).  I have edited the question above to show more of the custom code.

Comment: FYI, for those of you that may run across this issue in the future.  I have created a sort of work-around for it.  I think this issue is created because in my report, I have to loop through the same set of data to capture different sub-totals.  So when I hit the print button, it actually shows the totals that have been re-calculated when the report looped through the second time to get the second set of data.  To get around this issue, I created a new set of totals variables which I initialized to zero.  I then only move the total value into these variables if they are zero.

Comment: That way, I make sure that I don't double the amounts when I am displaying them for printing.